# Why bluetooth or USB 3.0 fails to load during booting?

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, bluetooth

Everytime I open my laptop with ubuntu 14.04 (dual booted with win 7) either bluetooth firmware fails to initialize or USB 3.0 ports. At this time also bluetooth is working fine but usb3.0 is not working. If I need to use any one of them, then I have to restart the system. If bluetooth gets load then Wifi icon get missing in menu bar.

The system is already up to date

`lsusb` gives

`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3121 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

EDIT: my laptop is hp 15-d103tx

`dmesg | grep Blue` gives

`[   18.539831] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   18.539850] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.539857] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.539861] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.539865] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   18.573689] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   18.573698] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   18.573702] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   18.609980] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   18.609983] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   18.609990] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized`

`uname -r` gives

`3.13.0-44-generic`

`lsb_release -a` gives

`No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us the maker and model of the computer where you have this issue. There probably is a firmware update for your computer that may fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to blacklist ath3k with

`echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modrobe.d/ath3k.conf` 
Reboot and open a terminal and enter `sudo modprobe ath3k` to see if it makes a difference with your USB 3.0 ports as ath3k could be trying to load the firmware at a bad time.

Comment: Added a carriage return to make the code appear all on one line, it should resolve the error

Comment: It should be `echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf`